# Optimizer Tuning in sklearn Gaussian Process Regressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm attempting to use a [GaussianProcessRegressor as part of scikit-learn 0.18.1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html)

I'm training on 200 data points and using 13 input features for my kernel - one constant multiplied by a radial basis function with twelve elements.  The model runs without complaints, but if I run the same script several times I notice that I sometimes get different solutions.  It may be worth noting that several of the optimized parameters are running into the bounds I've provided them (I'm currently working out which features matter).

I've tried increasing the parameter `n_restarts_optimizer` to 50, and while this takes considerably longer to run it doesn't eliminate the element of apparent randomness.  It seems possible to change the optimizer itself, though I've had no luck.  From a quick scan it seems the most similar syntactically are scipy's `fmin_tnc` and `fmin_slsqp` (other optimizers do not include bounds).  However, using either of those cause other issues: for example, `fmin_tnc` does not return the value of the objective function at its minimum.

Are there any suggestions for how to have a more deterministic script?  Ideally I'd like it to print the same values regardless of iteration, because as it stands it feels a bit like a lottery (and therefore drawing any conclusions is questionable).

A snippet of the code I'm using:

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor as GPR
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel as C

lbound = 1e-2
rbound = 1e1
n_restarts = 50
n_features = 12 # Actually determined elsewhere in the code
kernel = C(1.0, (lbound,rbound)) * RBF(n_features*[10], (lbound,rbound))
gp = GPR(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=n_restarts)
gp.fit(train_input, train_outputs)
test_model, sigma2_pred = gp.predict(test_input, return_std=True)
print gp.kernel_
```

Comment: You might try editing your question to be less opinion based. Is there a way to phrase your question that's has a (mostly) objectively correct answer?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, @Ares.

Comment: Check the documentation of all the methods or classes you use in your code to see if any of them include a 'random_state' parameter. If yes, set it to a fixed value

Comment: Hi @Andrew, I'm able to use the optimizer 'fmin_l_bfgs_b' only. Any idea on how to use 'fmin_tnc' and 'fmin_slsqp'? I've seen their documentation, however, still could not figure out the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

This uses random values to [initialize optimization](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#gaussian-process):

> As the LML may have multiple local optima, the optimizer can be
>   started repeatedly by specifying n_restarts_optimizer.

As far as I understand, there will always be a random factor. Sometimes it will find local minima, which are the bounds you've mentioned.

If your data allows it (invertible X matrix) You can use normal equation if it suits your needs, no random factor there.

You can do (something like a random forest) sampling on top of this, where you run this algorithm several times and choose the best fit or the common value: You will have to weigh consistency versus accuracy.

Hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: So to be clear, how would you use the normal equation as part of a Gaussian process?  I'm only familiar with that technique in linear regression.

Comment: I'm offering to switch methods. For example, If you are using Gaussian Process as a method to model and forecast, you can run iterations of non linear transformations and linear regression on your 200 data points. For the linear regression  you can use the normal equation (MLS). It is a trade off of consistency for the loss of uncertainty information for your forecasted value.